# Delete parent element on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to delete the li when I click the button with a span but so far no success.

```js
//delete testCase row when click delete button
$("a[id^='delete-']").click(function() {
  console.log('clicked');
  $(this).remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">

<ul id="testCaseList" class="list-group">
  <li class="list-group-item justify-content-between">test1<a class="action-icon" id="delete-test1" name="test1"><span class="fa fa-trash"></span></a></li>
  <li class="list-group-item justify-content-between">test2<a class="action-icon" id="delete-test2" name="test2"><span class="fa fa-trash"></span></a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 5):

This issue is because you delete `this` only, ie. the `a`. You need to traverse the DOM to find the parent `li`, then remove that:

```js
$("a[id^='delete-']").click(function() {
  console.log('clicked');
  $(this).closest('li').remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">

<ul id="testCaseList" class="list-group">
  <li class="list-group-item justify-content-between">test1<a class="action-icon" id="delete-test1" name="test1"><span class="fa fa-trash"></span></a></li>
  <li class="list-group-item justify-content-between">test2<a class="action-icon" id="delete-test2" name="test2"><span class="fa fa-trash"></span></a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: span's parent is `li`.  so just parent should do.

Comment: True, although I prefer `closest()` as it's more robust should the HTML be changed in the future.

Comment: Not being tightly coupled is a great thing.

Comment: lol I copied my code to stackoverflow and i see clicked on console but not on my code. wth. I can't trigger the jquery function

Comment: Can you help me on chat pls :/

Comment: If you check the console do you see any errors? Are you running your code in a document.ready handler? Have you included jquery properly?

Comment: Yes jquery is included, there is no errors. The event just doesn't get fired. I copied the html from the page so everything is the same. Can you just please help me 2 min on chat?

Comment: Sorry, I can't really help without seeing an example of your problem. As you can see from the snippet, this works fine.

Comment: Maybe I can use teamviewer?

Comment: Try giving the `a` a `href` attirbute

Answer (score 1):

You have to delete the parent. Not just itself.

```js
//delete testCase row when click delete button
$("a[id^='delete-']").click(function() {
  console.log('clicked');
  $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">


<ul id="testCaseList" class="list-group">

  <li class="list-group-item justify-content-between">test1<a class="action-icon" id="delete-test1" name="test1"><span class="fa fa-trash"></span></a></li>
  <li class="list-group-item justify-content-between">test2<a class="action-icon" id="delete-test2" name="test2"><span class="fa fa-trash"></span></a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You  are currently targeting the `span` not it's parent `li` which causing the deletion of `span`. Target the parent of clicked `span` by changing `$(this).remove();` to `$(this).parent().remove();` .

```js
//delete testCase row when click delete button
$("a[id^='delete-']").click(function() {
  console.log('clicked');
  $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
<ul id="testCaseList" class="list-group">

  <li class="list-group-item justify-content-between">test1<a class="action-icon" id="delete-test1" name="test1"><span class="fa fa-trash"></span></a></li>
  <li class="list-group-item justify-content-between">test2<a class="action-icon" id="delete-test2" name="test2"><span class="fa fa-trash"></span></a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the `li` you can use jQuery [**closest**](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) to get to the outer `li` and remove that.

```
$(this).closest('li').remove();
```

```js
//delete testCase row when click delete button
$("a[id^='delete-']").click(function() {
  console.log('clicked');
  $(this).closest('li').remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">

<ul id="testCaseList" class="list-group">

  <li class="list-group-item justify-content-between">test1<a class="action-icon" id="delete-test1" name="test1"><span class="fa fa-trash"></span></a></li>
  <li class="list-group-item justify-content-between">test2<a class="action-icon" id="delete-test2" name="test2"><span class="fa fa-trash"></span></a></li>
</ul>
```